# Puppet: how to add a line to an existing file

Tags: puppet

I am trying to add a line to an existing file /etc/fuse.conf. I tried this

added a folder two folders under modules directory

```
sudo mkdir /etc/puppet/modules/test
sudo mkdir /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests
```

Then created a test.pp file and added following lines

```
sudo vim /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/test.pp

file { '/etc/fuse.conf':
  ensure => present,
}->
file_line { 'Append a line to /etc/fuse.conf':
  path => '/etc/fuse.conf',
  line => 'Want to add this line as a test',
}
```

After that I ran this command

```
puppet apply /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/test.pp
```

Then I opened this file `/etc/fuse.conf` and there was no change in the file. The line was not added to the file. I don't understand what I am missing here. How can I do this?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36045455/781723, http://serverfault.com/q/764220/111679, http://superuser.com/q/1053789/93541.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Note according to an edit to the crosspost at Serverfault, the OP's code started working for them after they did a `vagrant provision`.  It's unclear what the nature of the underlying problem was.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. I ran the same test you did without an issue, and as long as you have `stdlib` installed in your environment you should be fine.

https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib

The results of running the same steps you outlined were successful for me:

```
[root@foreman-staging tmp]# puppet apply /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/test.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for foreman-staging.kapsch.local in environment production in 0.18 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/etc/fuse.conf]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File_line[Append a line to /etc/fuse.conf]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.24 seconds
```

What did your puppet run output?

Answer (score 0):

You should use templates (ERB) to handle file configuration. Its easier and cleaner.

Check the puppet docs for it in :
https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template.html

There are other options though. e.g. Augeas which is an API for file configuration and integrate very well with Puppet. http://augeas.net/index.html

[]'s

Comment: how does erb template help  to add a line to an existing file?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this. If it's ini file you can use `ini_setting`. If it's supported by augeas you can use that. Otherwise try specifying the after parameter to file_line